# How to add a changelistener to a fxml sheet for a scroll bar for JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

Alright, I am currently using a Gridpane to represent a table and I need to be able to scroll down this Gridpane and maybe show/don't show certain rows as I scroll.  I have a scroll bar which I can move up and down but nothing happens, obviously.

I'm using Scene Builder and I've tried placing my ChangeListener in nearly all of the possible drop down boxes in SceneBuilder under the code tab.  I am hoping there is a way to add the listener manually in the fxml document.

This is what my current changelistener looks like.

```
@FXML
public void changed(ChangeListener<? extends Number> pink, Number newValue) {
    Grid.setLayoutY(-newValue.doubleValue());
}
```

And here is the one line of the FXML sheet for the Scrollbar.

```
<ScrollBar fx:id="Scrolly" layoutX="841.0" layoutY="3.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="543.0" />
```

Honestly, I doubt the listener will even work once it's linked.  I can figure out how to make it work on my own, I just want it to be linked to the scrollbar.

Comment: Why don't you just place the `GridPane` in a `ScrollPane`?

Comment: That's a thing?  I shall certainly try this!